# Use Font.Color as Condition in If Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to use the font color as a condition to check against in an if statement.  It seems incredibly easy, but VBA doesn't seem to be able to do it.

I can't show my actual code as it has proprietary information in it, but I have even tried a simple version of my code with no avail.  That code is shown below.

```
Sub Testing()

Cells(1,1).Font.Color = -16776961
If Cells(1,1).Font.Color = -16776961 Then
     Cells(1,3) = "Worked!"
Else
     Cells(1,3) = "Didn't Work!"
End If

End Sub
```

The first line of code actually changes the font color or cell A1 to red.  However the conditional statement doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Why are you using a negative value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [RGB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function) function instead. (Not sure where the negative value comes from anyway?)

```
Sub Testing()

Cells(1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
If Cells(1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
     Cells(1, 3) = "Worked!"
Else
     Cells(1, 3) = "Didn't Work!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I recorded a macro of me setting the font color and that is what excel used, so I used the same thing.  Forgot about RGB.  That worked.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `RGB` like this:

```
Cells(1,1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
If Cells(1,1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
     Cells(1,3) = "Worked!"
Else
     Cells(1,3) = "Didn't Work!"
End If
```

Comment: I recorded a macro of me setting the font color and that is what excel used, so I used the same thing. Forgot about RGB. That worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help. don't forget to mark one of our awnsers as accepted. SJR posted their awnser a couple seconds sooner then mine so you should mark theirs. :)